# How to write a txt with the following list using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am using pandas to process a excel file my code looks as follows:

```
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")

important_Parameters="bash generate.sh --companyCode"+" "+df[u'Company Code '].astype(str)+" "+"--isaADD"+df[u'TP Interchange Address '].astype(str)+" "+"--gsADD"+" "+df[u'TP Functional Group Address '].astype(str)

print(important_Parameters)
```

Everything works well, when I print my code it looks fine, I wish to write a txt file with the contain of my object called:

```
important_Parameters
```

I tried with:

```
important_Parameters.to_pickle("important.txt")
```

but the result does not seem like the printing, I believe that is due to the way that I took to write in disk,

I also tried with:

```
important_Parameters.to_string("importantParameters2.txt")
```

However this gave me a more friendly representation of the data but the result is including the number of the raw and also the rows's are not completed they look as follows:

```
bash generate.sh --companyCode 889009d --isaADD...
```

it is showing this ...

I would like to appreciate any suggestion to produce a simple .txt file called importante.txt with my result, the containing of important_Parameters, thanks for the support

I order to include more details my output looks like, I mean the result of the print:

```
0       bash generate.sh --companyCode 323232 --isaADD...
1       bash generate.sh --companyCode 323232 --isaADD...
2       bash generate.sh --companyCode 323232 --isaADD...
```

Comment: I agree I already tried with that method but it is not giving me the complete row's, I stated that above for more details thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: Just use the regular `open` function passing the `w` mode parameter. May I also suggest using the `string.format` function with dict parameters, to neaten up that string building code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panda dataframes have more than a few methods for saving to files. Have you tried `important_Parameters.to_csv("important.csv")`? I'm not certain what you want the output to look like.

If you want it tab-separated, you can try:
    `important_Parameters.to_csv("important.csv", sep='\t')`

If the file absolutely must end in `.txt`, just change it to: `important_Parameters.to_csv("important.txt")`. CSVs are just specifically formatted text files so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This was really helpful however it is also including the number of the raw and some quotes for every raw as follows: "4881 bash generate.sh - ... --gsADD 814592838", I would like to write it without the double quotes and the number of the raw that is including, thanks a lot for the support this is a small issue,

Comment: Try telling the method to not row names? `important_Parameters.to_csv("important.txt", index=False)`. See here for more arguments: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html. You could pass `quotechar=None` or try `quotechar=''`.